# User model mixin with django

Tags: django, mixins

I'm creating a custom `User` model in Django. I already had a base class for my models, which I now separated using a mixin:

```
from django.db.models import Manager as DjangoModel

class ModelMixin(DjangoModel):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    objects = Manager() # Not relevant

    creation_date = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
        help_text=_('The date in which the database entry was created'),
        verbose_name=_('Creation date'))

    last_update = DateTimeField(auto_now=True,
        help_text=_('The last time that the database entry was updated'),
        verbose_name=_('Last update'))

class Model(ModelMixin):

    class Meta(ModelMixin.Meta):
        abstract = True
```

`Model` is supposed to be a base class of nearly all models I create. In this case, I'm trying to inherit from `AbstractBaseUser` and `ModelMixin`:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, ModelMixin):

    objects = UserManager()

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    email = EmailField(unique=True,
        help_text=_('Email address'),
        error_messages={
            'unique': _('This email address is already registered.')
        }
    )

    is_active = BooleanField(
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Whether the user is active')
    )
```

However, the mixin migrations are *not* being applied, as I can see be describing the table on the database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "futils_user" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "password" varchar(128) NOT NULL, "last_login" datetime NULL, "email" varchar(254) NOT NULL UNIQUE, "is_active" bool NOT NULL);
```

Notice that the `creation_date` and `last_update` fields are not there. What's wrong with doing it in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `from django.db.models import Manager as DjangoModel` instead of from `django.db.models import Model as DjangoModel`.
As the fields are not defined on a subclass of `Model` Django doesn't pick them up as valid fields.

Comment: Oh :\ nice catch... Thank you! (I'll accept in 10m, SO makes me wait)